# Mac C/C++ Eclipse Debugger hangs

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, debugging

When I try to use the debugger on a simple test project the console dumps out the following:

warning: `/var/folders/s1/dxx9glzn45j6x2ypzk9xkjnc0000gp/T/Test-0061ba.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
$1 = 0xff
The target endianness is set automatically (currently little endian)
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.

Launching the debugger gets 99% complete and gets stuck! It just hangs there for awhile and when I try to terminate the connection nothing happens. Then when I go to shut down eclipse I usually have to force quit it :( Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by correcting the gdb-cert. Make sure you select code signing "Always trust"